# Convert time string from unix time command like 10m20.5s into time format in excel

Tags: excel

I have time data from the unix time command like
203m53.5s

I have this data in excel. I want it to be converted to Excell time format so I can do mathematical operations like sum and averages over them.

How can I do this

Comment: still learning the ropes. Have addressed your concerns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `m` with `:` and the `s` with `""`:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"m",":"),"s","")
```

Now that the time is in a format that Excel will recognize we need to change it from string text to a number.  The `--` is forcing the string into a number by performing a mathematical process of multiplying `-1 * -1` to it.

It can be replaced by `TIMEVALUE()`

Then format the cell with a custom format of:

```
[mm]:ss.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a forumala to strip out the m and s and use those values for time in a new column in Excel.

Assume the Unix data is in column A.

=(LEFT($A1,FIND("m",$A1)-1)*60+MID($A1,FIND("m",$A1)+1, LEN($A1)-FIND("m",$A1)-1)/84600

then format the cell as custom and choose the time without the AM/PM

Breakdown:
(get the minutes by finding "m")
multiply by 60 to convert to seconds
+ (get the seconds by starting at the location of m, +1 to the location of m-length of the whole string)
-1 to account for the actual "s"
Then divide the whole thing by 84600 to convert to time as a decimal